# Wordpress PHPmailer not working

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I am trying to use the following code to send an email from a WordPress plugin

```
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpmailer.php'); 
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
            $mail->IsHTML(false);
            $mail->SetFrom(($enquiry_informations['display_email_address']!="")?$enquiry_informations['display_email_address']:"", "Autoquote");
            $mail->AddAddress($customer_email_address, $customer_email_name);
            $mail->Subject = $enquiry_informations['enquiry_autoresponse_subject'];
            $mail->Body = $autoresponse_msg;
            if($enquiry_informations['enquiry_autoresponse_attachment']!==NULL&&$enquiry_informations['enquiry_autoresponse_attachment']!==""){
                $mail->addAttachment(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "attachments/" . $enquiry_informations['enquiry_autoresponse_attachment']);
            }
            $info = $mail->Send();
        if($info){
        echo "Sent";
}else{
    echo "Failed";
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

however, I receive the following error:
The following From address failed: root@localhost : Called Mail() without being connected.
I did a little bit of googling and found out it could be something to do with protocol. This is from a wordpress plugin so I would like the code to be flexible(so that it can be used anywhere. So the varying protocol cannot get into the way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not pass all necessary values when using it. When you use `isSMTP()` method you have to provide the following information also:

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
```

Read [here](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) how to use the class properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way around is to use the mail helper within Wordpress.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

The error is probably caused because you are missing the right SMTP configuration, I don't know and couldn't find how you can adapt the Wordpress configuration though..

Hoping this helps you out a little!